# method that sorts an NSMutableArray of custom objects then returns an NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning objective-C and it's my first post, be gentle. I have searched the site and re-read my learning material but not sure what I'm not understanding/doing right. 
my objective is to add a method to an existing class that returns an NSArray of the top three most valuable "stocks" in an array. I have a working "stock" class, with a "valueInDollars" method, and a "portfolio" class that can hold instances of my stock class. I am using NSSortDescriptor to sort my NSMutableArray of stocks by their valueInDollars then return a copy of the mutable array with the top three values. here is my BNRStockHolding.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @class BNRPortfolio;

    @interface BNRStockHolding : NSObject

   {
        // declare instance variables
        float _purchaseSharePrice;
        float _currentSharePrice;
        int _numberOfShares;
        // add an instance variable that will allow us to print out the solution with less code
        NSString *_stockName;

    }
    // create a holder to use in the sorting method of BNRPortfolio
    @property (nonatomic, weak) BNRPortfolio *holder;

    // accesor methods declared
    - (float)purchaseSharePrice;
    - (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p;
    - (float)currentSharePrice;
    - (void)setCurrentSharePrice:(float)c;
    - (int)numberOfShares;
    - (void)setNumberOfShares:(int)n;
    - (NSString *)stockName;
    - (void)setStockName:(NSString *)s;
    - (void)addYourselfToArray:(NSMutableArray *)theArray;

    // instance methods below are defined in .m file as they are the result of
    // a mathematical equation using the instance variables above
    - (float)costInDollars;
    - (float)valueInDollars;

    @end
```

And my BNRPortfolio.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    // use @class so we can declare that this portfolio class will access the
    // 'valueInDollars' instance variable from the BNRStockHolding class
    @class BNRStockHolding;

    @interface BNRPortfolio : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *holdings;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *mostValuableHoldings;

    - (float)totalValue;
    - (void)addHolding:(BNRStockHolding *)h;
    - (void)removeHolding:(BNRStockHolding *)r;

    @end
```

And BNRPortfolio.m file:

```
#import "BNRPortfolio.h"
    #import "BNRStockHolding.h"

    @interface BNRPortfolio ()

    {
        NSMutableArray *_holdings;
        NSMutableArray *_mostValuableHoldings;
    }

    @end

    @implementation BNRPortfolio

    - (void)setHoldings:(NSArray *)s
    {
        _holdings = [s mutableCopy];
    }

    - (NSArray *)holdings
    {
        return [_holdings copy];
    }

    - (void)setMostValuableHoldings:(NSArray *)m
    {
        _mostValuableHoldings = [m mutableCopy];
    }

    - (NSArray *)mostValuableStocks;
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *highToLow = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"holder.valueInDollars" ascending:NO];
        [_holdings sortUsingDescriptors: @[highToLow]];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (BNRStockHolding *m in _holdings) {
                [_mostValuableHoldings addObject:m];
                break;
             }
        }
        return [_mostValuableHoldings copy];
    }

    - (void)addHolding:(BNRStockHolding *)h
    {
        // is the holdings array nil?
        if (!_holdings) {
            // create the array
            _holdings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        // add the holding in to the holdings array
        [_holdings addObject:h];
    }

    // describe how removeHolding works
    - (void)removeHolding:(BNRStockHolding *)r
    {
        if (r) {
            [_holdings removeObject:r];
        }
    }

    - (float)totalValue
    {
        // add the currentValue values of all holdings in the holdings array by iterating through
        // it and returning the sum
        float sum = 0;
        for (BNRStockHolding *h in _holdings) {
            sum += [h valueInDollars];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // change the description property to return an NSString with the total value of the portfolio
    - (NSString *)description
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<stock portfolio with a total value of %.2f>", self.totalValue];
    }


    @end
```

Some of you may recognize the names of the classes as I am following the Big Nerd Ranch guide on Objective-C and I have not renamed my classes. I have already searched the dedicated BNR forums for a solution and posted my issue there but to no avail and the solution is not given in the book. I desperately want to learn and understand exactly why this isn't working so please be detailed with your answer. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your `mostValuableStocks` method should be

```
_mostValuableHoldings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Which is to say that I don't see any code that alloc/inits that array.

Comment: First off, thank you all- @Avt @hypercrypt and @user3386109 - for your answers. I have found that changing the code in my `- (NSArray *)mostValuableHoldings;` portion of my method to include a simple alloc/init of the NSMutableArray did the trick. However, I was getting an array of the same three stocks due to an error in my iteration process so I changed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
NSSortDescriptor *highToLow = 
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"holder.valueInDollars" ascending:NO];
```

to

```
NSSortDescriptor *highToLow = 
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"valueInDollars" ascending:NO];
```

or

```
NSSortDescriptor *highToLow = 
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"SELF.valueInDollars" ascending:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
- (NSArray *)mostValuableStocks
{
    return [[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(BNRStockHolding *h1, BNRStockHolding *h2) {
        return [@([h1 valueInDollars]) compare:@([h2 valueInDollars])];
    }] subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){0, 3}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to help those having the same issue, here is the portion I changed to fix things in the `BNRPortfolio.m` file:

```
- (NSArray *)mostValuableHoldings;
{
if (!_mostValuableHoldings) {
    _mostValuableHoldings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
NSSortDescriptor *highToLow = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"valueInDollars" ascending:NO];
[_holdings sortUsingDescriptors: @[highToLow]];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        [_mostValuableHoldings addObject:_holdings[i]];
    }
return [_mostValuableHoldings copy];
}
```